# Code not working. The user is not being removed from the database.

Tags: javascript, php

```
<html>    
<div class="container">
  <div class="row vertical-center-row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4">
            <h3>Update/Remove Users</h3>
            <br>
<div class="form-group">               
<form method='POST' action='delete.php?rfidcode="<?php echo $_GET['rfidcode']?>"'>
       <label for="name">Are you sure that want to delete this user?</label>
       <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn- primary">Yes
       <button type="submit" onclick="window.location.href='http://localhost:8080/accesspi/users.php'" class="btn btn-primary">No </button>
       </form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<?php
 if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
$sqladd = "delete from users where rfidcode = '".$_GET['rfidcode']."'";

//update
if (($conn->query($sqladd))) {
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("Successfully removed")';
        echo '</script>';
    }
}
?>
</html>
```

I have the following code, that doesn't work. It doesn't remove the user from the database and has also a problem on **line 9** because it prints in the website **"?>**. The javascript code it is also not executed.

**P.S** The **db.php** file is included on the top of the code, but i didn't write it here. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: `method='POST'action` add a space.

Comment: the space it's added. No problem resolved.

Comment: It's not the problem, but it's a problem waiting to happen: Your code is **wide open** to SQL-injection attacks. Obligatory links: http://xkcd.com/327/, http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: @iris96 what is the current page called?

Comment: @T.J. Crowder yes I know it, this is only the beginning because I want first that it works

Comment: @Script47 The current page it's called delete.php

Comment: I fail to see any reason to write code you know is broken, debug it to the point the page basically works, all just so you can rewrite it again later properly.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have all the files that i nedd in my pc, just copy and paste. That's not my problem. I want that this code WORKS

Comment: If I take that and dump it into a PHP page, stubbing out the SQL parts, it works. Hopefully that at least narrows down the problem for you.

Comment: I don't know what it's going wrong here :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose your `delete` doesn't work because `isset($_POST["submit"])` is `false`. Why it can be `false`?

It's either not set or set to `NULL`.
Check your `$_POST` array - all chances there will be no key `submit`. This happens because you didn't set `value` attribute of submit button:

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
```

After that - check `$_POST`.

Comment: Did you print `$_POST`? What it shows? Are you sure `$conn` is defined? Are you sure that `rfid` exists?

Comment: I printed it, but shows nothing. Yes all these are defined

Comment: When you load page for the first time - it sure empty. Does it show anything when you hot the button? `var_dump` it

Comment: Also remove double quotes from here `rfidcode="<?php echo $_GET['rfidcode']?>"` . Do you even try to see html-code? Obviously it will be `rfidcode="22"`

Comment: that's the result of var_dump: string(44) "delete from users where rfidcode ='"4a19ad"'". How can I remove all of this "" ?

Comment: Extra quotes came form here `rfidcode="<?php echo $_GET['rfidcode']?>"` **Remove them**

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH. IT WORKS NOW :D

Answer (score 0):

Your code have some errors try replacing this part...

```
<div class="form-group"><form method='POST' action='delete.php?rfidcode="<?php echo $_GET['rfidcode']?>"'><label for="name">Are you sure that want to delete this user?</label><button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn- primary">Yes</button> <button type="submit" onclick="window.location.href='http://localhost:8080/accesspi/users.php'" class="btn btn-primary">No </button></form></div>
```

Comment: Can you posr the updated code now after replacing to see what you are using now....

Comment: I did it. Now it works the javascript part but the user is there :/. He is notremoved from the database

Comment: Since JavaScript is working that means all parts are working except the database query part, try replacing the query for something else and see if it runs.....

Comment: I tried to give the rfid code a value so the query does not become the rfidcode from the $_GET, and like this the query works

Comment: Well then $_GET is not working properly..., ok i can suggest you something like replace form action='delete.php'.. and than just get the rfidcode with a hidden input like in the form <input type="hidden" name="rfidcode" value ="<?php echo $_GET['rfidcode']?>">  and after that replace in your query $_GET['rfidcode'] with $_POST['rfidcode']